# JSP "cannot be resolved to a type", "unable to compile"

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I made a Tomcat project but I have a problem; I cannot use my own class.
This is an Example:

MyContext/test.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" import="myPackage.*" %>
<%=new MyClass()%>
```

MyContext/WEB-INF/MyPackage/MyClass.java

```
package myPackage;
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass{
    public String toString(){
        return "this is the string from my class!";
    }
}
```

Directory tree:

```
MyContext
|---test.jsp
`---WEB-INF
    `---classes
        `---myPackage
            |---MyClass.class
            `---MyClass.java
```

And I got an error when I accessed MyContext/test.jsp:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
MyClass cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%@page language="java" import="myPackage.*" %>
2: <%=new MyClass()%>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

My environment is
Ubuntu Server 14.04,
Java Version 1.7.0_55,
Tomcat 7.

Please help me.

Comment: `myPackage` in the directory tree vs. MyPackage in the imports?

Comment: You made a Java EE project, Tomcat is just web container to deploy the project.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I changed `import="MyPackage.*"` to `import="myPackage.*"`, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Post the new StackTrace here.

Comment: I changed the `test.jsp` source and the error code.

Answer (score 1):

Change `MyClass.java`

Change `package myPackage` to `MyPackage`

Answer (score 1):

You have written the wrong package name, as mentioned in other answers.

Java is **Case - Sensitive**.

`myPackage` and `MyPackage` both are different.

I would suggest you to *always* follow naming conventions, so that you don't get errors like this again.

[Check This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Package name should always start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0):

Package names are case sensitive. Change your import line like this:

```
<%@page language="java" import="myPackage.*" %>
```

Also make sure the package directory is named `myPackage`, not `MyPackage`.